# Could there be extra container template arguments added in future C++ revisions?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, variadic-templates

I'm working on (yet another) serialization toolkit that supports C++ standard containers. In order to make my toolkit more future-proof, I'm considering using variadic template arguments like this

```
template <typename... Ts>
void (Writer& w, const std::vector<Ts...>& v) noexcept
{
    using ValueType = typename std::vector<Ts...>::value_type;
    // serialize vector elements
}
```

instead of fixed number of template arguments like this

```
template <typename T, typename A>
void (Writer& w, const std::vector<T,A>& v) noexcept
{
    using ValueType = T;
    // serialize vector elements
}
```

Is there any chance that extra template arguments could be added to containers in future C++ revisions?

Comment: Are you asking whether it would be technically *possible* or whether it is to any degree *likely*?

Comment: The committee could, but I doubt they will.  Too much legacy code that assumes the number of parameters.  Especially pre-C++11 code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 whynotboth.jpg  ;-)

Comment: Really though if you are making a modern library, and you can wait for C++20 and concepts, then what you do is use concepts for the different overloads of the function.  i.e., one overload for contiguous containers, one for associative containers, sequence containers, and so on.

Comment: And your "future proof" doesn't handle non-type template parameters.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm targeting C+11 for now and will (hopefully) overhaul it to C++20 once it becomes more mainstream.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. That probably settles my "dilemma" right there.

Comment: You could do the same thing in C++11, it will just be a lot more work as the syntax is a lot more verbose.  Eric Niebler's range v3 library did the same thing (made their own concepts) since they didn't exist yet.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm 75% of the way of doing container concepts in C++11, but it's not easy (for me). The same template class does the serialization work for contiguous/sequential contains and uses compile-time member function detection to "figure out" the best way to handle the container.

Comment: I would accept an answer that states adding arguments would break legacy code, and that variadic type arguments won't handle non-type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As NathanOliver pointed out in the comments, adding container template parameters would break lots of legacy code that assumes the number of parameters. It is therefore doubtful that the committee would do such as thing.

As Jarod42 pointed out in the comments, `<typename Ts...>` doesn't handle non-type template parameters that could be possibly (but doubtfully, see above) added in the future.

There's therefore probably no benefit in using `<typename Ts...>` over `<typename T, typename A>`, except that it's shorter for containers such as `unordered_map` (e.g. `<typename K, typename T, typename H, typename E, typename A>`).